# Replacing Values With Column Headers Using a For Loop and Condition With Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am using pandas to try to replace each "Y" value in the "Option" columns with the Options Name (e.g. the column header)

[Current Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eijbW.png)

Below is the expected output, but I cannot figure out how to write the loop to replace values with the column header.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9npTx.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for column in dataframe.columns:
    dataframe.loc[dataframe[column]=='Y', column] = column
```

you're basically iterating over the columns and replacing cells that have a 'Y' with its column name. btw, 'column' above is just an arbitrary name: it could be 'x' and it work all the same.